# Fatal error: Call to a member function get_page_permastruct() on a non-object

Tags: plugin-development, functions, fatal-error

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_page_permastruct() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\link-template.php on line 358
```

when i call this function

```
function pn_create_page() {
    global $wpdb;
    $check_page = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT option_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."pn_options WHERE id = '10'" );

    // if no page create one
    if ($check_page==''){
        $pagedata = array(
        'post_content'   => 'Page content will go here.',
        'post_title'     => 'Page Title',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'post_author'    => 1,
        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
        'comment_status' => 'closed'
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $pagedata );
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.'pn_options', array('option_value'=>$post_id), array('id'=>'10'));

    // if page excist do nothing    
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

The line wich causes the error is this one

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $pagedata );
```

Also i get this notice

```
Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\post.php on line 3688
```

from the same line.....

Don´t know whats wrong.... Any ideas?

I want to create a wordpress page directly from a plugin....

Comment: when do you call `pn_create_page`?

Comment: In the main file from the plugin after the functions file where this function is in.

Comment: that's too early, you need to hook it to an [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) that runs after everything is set up, like `init`.

Comment: After i put it in the buttom of all and call add_action('init', 'pn_create_page'); its working now. Thank you! Can you explain why it must called later and with an action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error get\_page\_permastruct()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75724/fatal-error-get-page-permastruct)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WordPress environment is not yet fully initialized when your plugin files are loaded, it's almost always too early to safely run code that interacts with core at that point.

WordPress achieves its initial state through a process which contains its own set of actions and filters, so plugins load before that happens to allow them to hook into that process.

The action and filter system is the basis of core / plugin interaction, just about everything a plugin does will be tied to an action or filter. It's a simple system that provides a roadmap of the whole request process, allowing you to manage the order of when your plugin code executes.